# MVC3 Entity Framework using default membership relationships

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1

I want to create a relationship between a custom table (Websites) and the default aspnet tables related to Users.

I'm using code-first so for most FK relationships I would just do

```
public ModelName ModelName { get; set; }
```

With this, EF will automatically create the FK relationships. Very easy.

What's confusing is the most effective way to hook into the aspnet users/membership table. Do I create a new model Users that acts as an interface so that I can implement custom user code?

Is there a best way to do this that fits well into EF best practices? I basically just want to relate a user to the Websites table/model so that EF can do its thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has few preconditions:

- ASP.NET tables must be in the same database as your own tables
- Previous precondition means that you must either create your database and tables manually (without automatic code-first generation) or you must use some custom initializer which will add non mapped ASP.NET tables as part of database recreation

If you want your model class to have relation with ASP.NET table you must model ASP.NET table as another entity. I'm not sure if you can use ASP.NET classes for that because for example `MembershipUser` doesn't have parameterless public constructor which is required for EF. So you will most probably need to create duplicate classes and their mappings and use these classes when referencing ASP.NET entities.

Comment: In your experience, do most applications in asp mvc use this convention, or is there another log in system that is typically used?

Answer (score 3):

"Do I create a new model Users that acts as an interface so that I can implement custom user code?"

If you want flexibility, I would say this is the way to go. This way it would be easier if you wanted to change to some sort of different Authentication DB structure in the future.

For example, have an "AppUser" Entity where the corresponding table has a foreign key to the "UserID" column of the aspnet_Membership table. This way you can simply add properties to your "AppUser" Entity instead of trying to change the MS table structure (which can be a real pain). You can still interact with the built-in MS Membership classes and functions from your MVC project using something like the MvcMembership starter Kit DLL's.

https://github.com/TroyGoode/MembershipStarterKit

Hope this helps!